# Changing the div content with a link in an div which leads to an externa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a task to solve and I am quite new in js and stuff, so please help me out on this.
I've got this in php(I use php cause I need to use databases as well):

What I want is to put external html contents in the container without reloading the whole page. Lets call the external contents `link1.html;link2.html`...

When load the page I want the container with the content of link1.html whick is also available and can be recalled by clicking link1.

I tried jquery and stuff but it was not really work for me. I'd like to use external js or ajax or jquery or something like that.
Please help!!!
Thank you in advance for everyone!

```
<div id="links">
    <ul>
        <li id="link1">link1</li>

        <li id="link2">link1</li>

        <li id="link3">link1</li>

        <li id="link4">link1</li>

    </ul>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Question not clear. Explain with code reference.

Comment: jQuery is the way to solve this. eg see [jQuery's .load](http://api.jquery.com/load/). jQuery is written in javascript. Ajax is how javascript loads stuff and if used by jQuery. Your terminology is a little off

Comment: Thanks Basic for the explanation:) about 2 weeks ago I did not even know what html is. So I know my terminology sucks.

Comment: <div id="links">
    <ul>
        <li id="link1">link1</li>

        <li id="link2">link1</li>

        <li id="link3">link1</li>

        <li id="link4">link1</li>

    </ul>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>

Where link1 makes link1.html to be in #container, 
link2 makes link2.html to be in #container,
link3 makes link3.html to be in #container,
link4 makes link4.html to be in #container.
And by default I would like link1.html to be in #container when the page loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `load()`, `$.get()` or `$.ajax` for loading *stuff*, an example:

```
<div id="links">
    <ul>
        <li id="link1"><a href='path'>link1</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
$('#links a').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#container').load(this.href); 
});
```

Comment: ok and where should I put the source of the content of the container?

Comment: and what should I do to for link1.html to be already in the container when the page has loaded?